# Inserting background image

Tags: css

Please excuse my simple question! I am very new to coding and have a simple question. I am currently setting up a website in Adobe Business catalyst and have a problem.

All I want to do is insert a background image into one of the modules. Ideally id like this image to resize depending on size of module.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="announcement-details">
  <h1>
    <span style="font-size: 28px; color: rgb(0, 174, 239);">{tag_subject}</span>
    <br>
    <span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 23px;">
    <br>
    <span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">
      {tag_body}
    </span>
    </span>
    <br>
  </h1> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span.my-class {
    background: url('/path/to/image') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a background image you can easily use the css *background* property to insert the image and set certain properties to the background image.

In this example I set the css property *background-size:cover* to the background image so that the image resizes depending on the container size.

http://jsfiddle.net/77wc17yo/4/

```
.parent {
    background:#fefefe;
    padding:120px;
    border:3px solid gold;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    background: url('https://eQ3Q') no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```